# How to debug Lightning components with Platform Cache?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, scratch-org, platform-cache

I am researching how to make use of [platform cache](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/platform_cache/units/platform_cache_get_started) in a lightning component to reduce the number of API calls that it will need to make. The problem is that when I push code for a Lightning component, it needs to be pushed to a scratch org, and platform cache specifically does not support scratch orgs. Is there a way to test a lightning component in a way that I can test it with platform cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have support for Platform Cache in scratch orgs on the roadmap. It's tentatively planned for Summer '19 at the moment.

The current (subject to change) plan is to allocate 3MB of cache to scratch orgs that request the feature, and to lower the minimum partition size to 1MB, since scratch orgs generally represent a single-developer environment rather than the multi-user environments the 5MB minimum was designed to serve.